# Getting blank page using RequireJS and Grunt

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, gruntjs

I'm going a bit crazy here. I'm trying to use Grunt to go through a large RequireJS-based project and combine and minify the results during the deployment process. Here is my grunt process (using grunt-contrib-requirejs):

```
requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: "public/js",
                mainConfigFile: "public/js/config.js",
                name: 'config',
                out: "public/js/optimized/script.min.js",
                preserveLicenseComments: false
            }
        }
    }
```

Initially, I was taking the outputted script and placing it in the HTML -- but this lead to the 'define is undefined' error that means that RequireJS wasn't evoked. So instead, I'm putting in the HTML like this:

```
<script data-main="js/optimized/script.min" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
```

However, now I'm only getting a blank page.

The closest thing I can find out there that sounds like this is [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404957), but's not being super helpful right now. For reference, I was using [this](https://github.com/donofkarma/backbone-require-template) as a starting point of my project -- however, when I run it, everything seems to be working for them but I can't find the differences.

Here is my config.js file:

```
require.config({

//Define the base url where our javascript files live
baseUrl: "js",

//Increase the timeout time so if the server is insanely slow the client won't burst
waitSeconds: 200,

//Set up paths to our libraries and plugins
paths: {
    'jquery': 'vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min',
    'underscore': 'vendor/underscore.min',
    'backbone': 'vendor/backbone.min',
    'marionette': 'vendor/backbone.marionette',
    'mustache': 'vendor/mustache.min',
    'bootstrap': 'vendor/bootstrap.min',
    'bootbox': 'vendor/bootbox.min',
    'jquery-ui': 'vendor/jquery-ui-1.10.2',
    'app-ajax': '../conf/app-ajax',
    'common': 'common',
    'moment': 'vendor/moment.min'
},

//Set up shims for non-AMD style libaries
shim: {
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },

    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },

    'marionette': {
        deps: ['backbone', 'underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Marionette'
    },

    'mustache': {
        exports: 'mustache'
    },

    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },

    'bootbox': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
        exports: 'bootbox'
    },

    'jquery-ui': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },

    'jquery-layout': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui']
    }

}
});

//Initalize the App right after setting up the configuration
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'common',
    'mustache',
    'bootbox',
    'controllers/GlobalController',
    'routers/GlobalRouter'
],
function ($, Backbone, Marionette, Common, Mustache, bootbox) {

    //Declare ECMAScript5 Strict Mode first and foremost
    'use strict';

    //Define the App Namespace before anything else
    var App = Common.app_namespace || {};

    //Create the Marionette Application
    App.Application = new Marionette.Application();

    //Add wrapper region, so we can easily swap all of our views in the controller in and out of this constant
    App.Application.addRegions({
        wrapper: '#wrapper'
    });        

    // Set up Initalizer (this will run as soon as the app is started)
    App.Application.addInitializer(function () {

        //Reach into Marionette and switch out templating system to Mustache
        Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate = function (rawTemplate) {
            return Mustache.compile(rawTemplate);
        };

        var globalController = new App.Controllers.GlobalController();

        var globalRouter = new App.Routers.GlobalRouter({
            controller: globalController
        });

        //Start Backbone History
        Backbone.history.start();

    });

    //Start Application
    App.Application.start();

}
);
```

Comment: None - that was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is the crazy simple fix:

In the module that's declared after the require.config, use 'require' instead of 'define' when declaring the module.

If you use 'define', it added 'config' as a dependency of that module, which broke the whole thing. Craziness!

Comment: Saved my day. I encountered the same issue.

Comment: Where exactly should `require` be used instead of `define`? I'm just getting into this and having the same problem and don't quite understand what you mean.